# NodeJs Mongoose record not populate for ref object array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am populating my data with the Query

```
User.find(query).populate([{path: 'messages',select: '_id'}]).exec(callback);
```

My user schema is like:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({firstname:{
    type:String,
    required : true,
    trim: true
},
name:{
    type:String,
    required : true,
    trim: true
},
messages : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Messages' }]
});
```

and Message schema is like :

```
const MessagesSchema = mongoose.Schema({        
user_id : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
message:{
    type:String,
    required : true,
    trim: true
},
isRead:{
    type:Boolean,
    required : true,
    default:false
}
});
```

Can anybody please help me to populate this.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting _id from messages, but you don't have _id field in your message schema.

Comment: while schema genetares document in mongodb it automatically create _id field for each document so i am using it.